# Are files I delete from my flash drive on windows gone?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I deleted some files from a FAT32 formatted flash drive on windows 8 by accident. I didn't panic because I thought I could recover them from the recycle bin but they are nowhere to be found. I take it windows does not have a .trash folder on removable drives like Mac and the files were simply deleted. Is this correct and if so is there still an easy way to recover the files?

Comment: did you do a shift+delete or just a delete?

Comment: It's quite possible that they were instantly removed from the file system. As always, you can try various "undelete" application to restore the file, like http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec Alternatively, try http://kickassundelete.sourceforge.net/ I just gave that a quick run on a FAT32 USB key of mine, quick and simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows only uses a [recycle Bin for internal drives or USB HDD drives](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/recycle_bin.mspx?mfr=true), [but not for FAT32 formatted USB drives](http://ask-leo.com/wheres_the_recycle_bin_on_my_usb_drive.html).

Use an undelete tool like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) to recover the deleted file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Recuva did an excellent job of successfully recovering the files. Thanks so much! Other software I tried was not working...

Comment: great to hear this :)

Answer (score 1):

[Get photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) and run it.

It is *very good* at finding image files on a deleted drive.  Its also free software, and arguably the gold standard for this kind of thing.

Comment: not just image files. pretty much any file with a consistent header and well documented format.